# Definition of 'soft' matrix rank

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, definition, matrix-rank

Is there a 'soft' version of the matrix rank where the rank of a matrix is a real number rather than an integer?

Suppose, for example, we have a matrix with $2$ row vectors, where one of the vectors is equal to the other one plus some small amount of 'noise'. In this case, using the usual, strict rank definition, the matrix will be of rank $2$ almost surely, although the matrix could be interpreted as less 'rankish' compared to a matrix consisting of perpendicular row vectors (which would be of rank $2$ too). However, it does not seem quite fair to treat both matrices in the same way.

Any help on this problem is appreciated.

Comment: You might want to take a look into a numerics textbook. In the case you described, some algorithms like for example Gaussian elimination will be badly conditioned. If someone has invented means to see that a priori and hence describing such "almost rank 1" matrices, you might find it there.
I think that some matrix norms gave information about that, but I might be mistaken here.

Comment: thanks Bente, your suggestion provides a nice direction to search along...

Comment: Are you acquainted with the condition number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume, you want something, that can be done by a standard singular value decomposition.

The smallest singular value denotes, how large the error in the matrix must be, to make one rank disappear. 
Closly related is the condition-number $\kappa$ of a matrix, which (in some sense) scales this value by the magnitude of the matrix.

Comment: I wonder whether eigenvalues ( near 0)  can be also used for this aim?

Comment: The singular values are the eigenvalues of $A^TA$, so there is a clear 1 to 1 correspondence. Any small eigenvalue will lead to a nearly singular matrix. The benefit of using the SVD is, that you get the basis of image space, kernel etc with it.

Comment: Ok. So singular values are preferable..

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if standard, but some texts use a "stable rank" defined as the ratio between squared Frobenius norm and the squared spectral norm of a matrix (equivalently the ratio of the sum of squares of all the singular values to the square of the max singular value).

For example, https://nickhar.wordpress.com/2012/02/29/lecture-15-low-rank-approximation-of-matrices/.

Answer (score 0):

I don't known if there is a standard way of defining the "soft" rank, but I think there is a way of intuitively measuring what you want.

You may view the rank of a matrix as the minimum number of vectors (rows/columns) you need to generate the others. Or as the dimension of the space that contains all the vectors. We will define how "close" a matrix is to be rank N based on how well do N vectors define the others.

Specifically, for a fixed rank N you iterate though all the combinations of N vectors. For each such combination, you compute the sum of sin(angle) between the remaining vectors and their projection on the subspace generated by the N selected vectors.

- For any N >= the true rank of the matrix, you will have this "closeness to rank N" measure equal to 0 (each remaining vector is inside the generated space, and the angle they make with their projection is 0).
- For N < the true rank, the measure will be a strictly positive real number less or equal to the number of remaining vectors, measuring how well can N vectors define the other ones.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use something like the sum of the sigmoid of the squares of eigenvalues. Anything maps to zero 0.

$$
\text{soft rank}(\epsilon) = \sum_i \phi(|\lambda_i|^2 / \epsilon)
$$
where $\phi(0) = 0, \phi(\infty) = 1$.
Not sure if I got that right but I think as $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$ you tend to the matrix rank.